# How can I route a nested resource to an alias?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, custom-routes, nested-routes

I know it's not advised to go more then 1 level deep in nested routes but here's what I have:

```
  resources :partners do
    resources :recommend_partners do
      resources :rec_partner_comments
    end
  end
```

Is there a way that I can call an alias to use the name_route

So instead of using

```
new_partner_recommend_partner_rec_partner_comments
```

I'll use something like

```
new_comment_on_pr
```

Just a thought...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always create a helper function

```
def new_comment_on_pr(*args)
  new_partner_recommend_partner_rec_partner_comments(*args)
end
```

Also do you know of a more clear route path syntax in Rails? Instead of

```
partner_recommend_partner_rec_partner_comments(partner, recommend_partner)
```

you can write

```
[partner, recomment_partner, :comments]
```

Comment: `[partner, recomment_partner, :comments]`
will get me the index!
The helper function works for my other routes but I don't know why it isn't working for this one..
if I use:
`new_partner_recommend_partner_rec_partner_comment`
in the show, or a helper function it still gives me the same error:
undefined method `new_partner_recommend_partner_rec_partner_comment'

Comment: And, as an extra information, I got that route from the rake routes in the console, so it shouldn't render and error... at least not an undefined method error...

Comment: The example i gave you will give you the index indeed. To get the path you want it should look like `[:new, partner, recommend_partner, :rec_partner_comment]`. Anyway if the `rake routes` displays this path then the helper should be available. I notice that your example contains `new_partner_recommend_partner_rec_partner_comments` instead of `new_partner_recommend_partner_rec_partner_comment` (notice the S at the end). Maybe this is the reason?

Comment: Nope, I just wrote it wrong the first time, it's without the S at the end...
But the [:new, partner, recommend_partner, :rec_partner_comment] works!!!
I'm just confused why the route shown in my rake routes gives me and undefined method error.. because I litterly copied from the console and pasted so I now it's exactly the same...